# Remove empty line below menu in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

[image: Unused space]

As you can see in the image I have a lot of empty space in Visual Studio 2019 just below the menu (marked in red). It looks like that line is there because of the three options on the right side of the screen (marked in green).

Is it possible to remove that whole line? For example by hiding the three options (Live Share, feedback and Preview|admin).

Comment: What about the Full-Screen mode that is enabled by `Shift+Alt+Enter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide Live Share, feedback and Preview|admin area with Visual Commander: https://visualstudioextensions.vlasovstudio.com/2019/03/19/freeing-screen-space-in-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: Well job, hiding these buttons gave me more space and now I have in a single line all toolbars I need