# Is there a way to hide feedback icon in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

The newly released Visual Studio 2019 goes a long way to save the screen real estate by moving the menus to the title bar, almost like in Full Screen mode. Unfortunately, even if all the toolbars are hidden, there's still Feedback icon on the right that occupies the whole toolbar space!
Is there a way to hide this icon and reclaim the screen space?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452578/remove-empty-line-below-menu-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove empty line below menu in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55452578/remove-empty-line-below-menu-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: What about the Full-Screen mode that is enabled by `Shift+Alt+Enter`?